# MVVM and DI with nested controls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I've been using MVVM for WPF quite a while now but I've always been doing it this way:

**ExampleView.xaml.cs** (namespace: Example.Views)

```
public partial class ExampleView
{
    public ExampleView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var viewModel = new ExampleViewModel();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

The **ExampleView.xaml** has no code concerning the `ExampleViewModel` except for bindings to properties.

**ExampleViewModel.cs** (namespace: Example.ViewModels)

```
public ExampleViewModel()
{
    // No important code in here concerning this topic. Code here is only used in this class.
}
```

Below is a simplified **MainWindowView.xaml**.

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Example.Views">
    <Grid>
        <views:ExampleView />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The **MainWindowView.xaml.cs** is similar to the ExampleView.xaml.cs. The **MainWindowViewModel.cs** has no important code concerning this topic.

Lastly, the **App.xaml** contains the `StartupUri="Views/MainWindowView.xaml"`.

If this is a good pattern or not, I got my application to work. Since the application is not maintainable by me alone anymore, 2-3 people are now working on it creating some problems. One person is doing the majority of the coding (ViewModels basically), one person is doing the GUI (Views) and one person is doing the "framework" coding. *(Using "" because this is not really a framework but I can't think of a better word for it.)*

Now, I'm the guy that is doing the framework coding and I've been reading up on several subjects like dependency injection and the code below is what I came up with using `UnityContainer` from Windows.

**ExampleView.xaml.cs** (namespace: Example.Views)

```
public partial class ExampleView
{
    public ExampleView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

The **ExampleView.xaml** has no code concerning the `ExampleViewModel` except for bindings to properties.

**ExampleViewModel.cs** (namespace: Example.ViewModels)

```
public string MyText { get; set; }

public ExampleViewModel(ILocalizer localizer)
{
    MyText = localizer.GetString("Title");
}
```

Below is a simplified **MainWindowView.xaml**.

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Example.Views">
    <Grid>
        <views:ExampleView DataContext="{Binding ExampleViewModel}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The **MainWindowView.xaml.cs** is similar to the ExampleView.xaml.cs.

**MainWindowViewModel.cs**

```
ExampleViewModel ExampleViewModel { get; set; }
private readonly ILocalizer _localizer;
private readonly IExceptionHandler _exHandler;

public MainWindowViewModel(ILocalizer localizer, IExceptionHandler exHandler)
{
    _localizer = localizer;
    _exHandler = exHandler;

    ExampleViewModel = new ExampleViewModel(localizer);
}
```

Lastly, the **App.xaml** does not contains the `StartupUri="..."` anymore. It's now done in **App.xaml.cs**. It's also here where the `UnityContainer is initialized.

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    // Base startup.
    base.OnStartup(e);

    // Initialize the container.
    var container = new UnityContainer();

    // Register types and instances with the container.
    container.RegisterType<ILocalizer, Localizer>();
    container.RegisterType<IExceptionHandler, ExceptionHandler>();
    // For some reason I need to initialize this myself. See further in post what the constructor is of the Localizer and ExceptionHandler classes.
    container.RegisterInstance<ILocalizer>(new Localizer()); 
    container.RegisterInstance<IExceptionHandler>(new ExceptionHandler());
    container.RegisterType<MainWindowViewModel>();

    // Initialize the main window.
    var mainWindowView = new MainWindowView { DataContext = container.Resolve<MainWindowViewModel>() };

    // This is a self made alternative to the default MessageBox. This is a static class with a private constructor like the default MessageBox.
    MyMessageBox.Initialize(mainWindowView, container.Resolve<ILocalizer>());

    // Show the main window.
    mainWindowView.Show();
}
```

For some reason I need to initialize the Localizer and ExceptionHandler classes myself. The Localizer and ExceptionHandler constructors are found below. Both have constructors with all arguments that have a default value. Adding constructors without arguments like

```
public ExceptionHandler() : this(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ErrorLogs", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".log")) { }
```

doesn't change a thing.

```
public Localizer(ResourceDictionary appResDic = null, string projectName = null, string languagesDirectoryName = "Languages", string fileBaseName = "Language", string fallbackLanguage = "en")
{
    _appResDic = appResDic ?? Application.Current.Resources;
    _projectName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(projectName) ? projectName : Application.Current.ToString().Split('.')[0];
    _languagesDirectoryName = languagesDirectoryName.ThrowArgNullExIfNullOrEmpty("languagesFolder", "0X000000066::The languages directory name can't be null or an empty string.");
    _fileBaseName = fileBaseName.ThrowArgNullExIfNullOrEmpty("fileBaseName", "0X000000067::The base name of the language files can't be null or an empty string.");
    _fallbackLanguage = fallbackLanguage.ThrowArgNullExIfNullOrEmpty("fallbackLanguage", "0X000000068::The fallback language can't be null or an empty string.");
    CurrentLanguage = _fallbackLanguage;
}

public ExceptionHandler(string logLocation = null, ILocalizer localizer = null)
{
    // Check if the log location is not null or an empty string.
    LogLocation = string.IsNullOrEmpty(logLocation) ? Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ErrorLogs", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".log") : logLocation;

    _localizer = localizer;
}
```

My big question now is if I'm approaching dependency injection correctly and if having several static classes that I initialize once are bad. Several topics I've read state that static classes are a bad-practice because of bad testability and tightly coupled code, but right now the tradeoffs of dependency injection are bigger than having static classes.

Doing dependency injection correctly would be a first step in having less tightly coupled code though. I like the approach with the static `MyMessageBox` I can initialize once and that it's globally available in the application. This is mainly for "easy usage" I guess cause I can simply call `MyMessageBox.Show(...)` instead of injecting this all the way down to the smallest element. I have a similar opinion about the `Localizer` and `ExceptionHandler` because these will be used even more.

A last concern I have is the following. Lets say I have a class with several arguments and one of the arguments is the `Localizer` (because this will be used in nearly any class). Having to add `ILocalizer localizer` every time

```
var myClass = new MyClass(..., ILocalizer localizer);
```

feels very annoying. This would push me towards a static Localizer I initialize once and having never to care about it anymore. How would this problem be tackled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a bunch of "Services" which are used in many classes, you can create a facade class which encapsulates the required services and inject the facade into your classes.

Advantage of doing so is, you can easily add other services to that facade and they'd be available in all other injected classes, without modifying the constructor parameters.

```
public class CoreServicesFacade : ICoreServicesFacade
{
    private readonly ILocalizer localizer;
    private readonly IExceptionHandler excaptionHandler;
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public ILocalizer Localizer { get { return localizer; } }
    public IExceptionHandler ExcaptionHandler{ get { return exceptionHandler; } }
    public ILogger Logger { get { return logger; } }

    public CoreServices(ILocalizer localizer, IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, ILogger logger)
    {
        if(localizer==null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("localizer");

        if(exceptionHandler==null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("exceptionHandler");

        if(logger==null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(logger);

        this.localizer = localizer;
        this.exceptionHandler = exceptionHandler;
        this.logger = logger;
    }
}
```

Then you can pass it to your classes:

```
var myClass = new MyClass(..., ICoreServicesFacade coreServices);
```

(which you shouldn't do anyway when using Dependency Injection, you shouldn't use `new` keyword, except for factories and models).

As for your ILocalizer and IExceptionHandler implementations... if your ExceptionHandler requires the Localizer and the localizer requires the string parameter, you have two options, depending on if the file name needs to be determined at a later point at run time or only once during the Application initialization.

**Important**

*Don't use optional constructor parameters if you want to use dependency injection. For DI, constructor parameters should declare the dependencies in constructor and constructor dependencies are always considered as mandatory (don't use `ILocalizer localizer = null` within the constructor).*

If you only create the logfile during the Applications initialization, it's quite easy

```
var logFilePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "ErrorLogs", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".log");
var localizer = new Localizer(...);
var exceptionHandler = new ExceptionHandler(logFilePath, localizer);
container.RegisterInstance<ILocalizer>(localizer); 
container.RegisterInstance<IExceptionHandler>(exceptionHandler);
```

Basically in your bootstrapper you instantiate and configure your Localizer and ExceptionHandler, then register it as instance with the container.

If for some reason, you need to determine the name of log filename or language at a later point (after Bootstrapper configuration & initialization), you need to use a different approach: You need a factory class.

The factory will be injected into your classes rather than the instance of ILocalizer/IExceptionHandler and create the instance of it when the parameters are known.

```
public interface ILocalizerFactory 
{
    ILocalizer Create(ResourceDictionary appResDic, string projectName);
}

public class ILocalizerFactory
{
    public ILocalizer Create(ResourceDictionary appResDic, string projectName)
    {
        var localizer = new Localizer(appResDic, projectName, "Languages",  "Language", "en");
        return localizer;
    }
}
```

Using the facade Example from above:

```
public class CoreServicesFacade : ICoreServicesFacade
{
    private readonly ILocalizer localizer;

    public ILocalizer Localizer { get { return localizer; } }

    public CoreServices(ILocalizerFactory localizerFactory, ...)
    {
        if(localizer==null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("localizerFactory");

        this.localizer = localizerFactory.Create( Application.Current.Resources, Application.Current.ToString().Split('.')[0]);
    }
}
```

***Caveats & tips***

**Move Default configuration outside of the classes itself**

Don't use such code inside your Localizer/ExceptionHandler classes.

```
_appResDic = appResDic ?? Application.Current.Resources;
_projectName = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(projectName) ? projectName : Application.Current.ToString().Split('.')[0];
_languagesDirectoryName = languagesDirectoryName.ThrowArgNullExIfNullOrEmpty("languagesFolder", "0X000000066::The languages directory name can't be null or an empty string.");
_fileBaseName = fileBaseName.ThrowArgNullExIfNullOrEmpty("fileBaseName", "0X000000067::The base name of the language files can't be null or an empty string.");
_fallbackLanguage = fallbackLanguage.ThrowArgNullExIfNullOrEmpty("fallbackLanguage", "0X000000068::The fallback language can't be null or an empty string.");
CurrentLanguage = _fallbackLanguage;
```

This pretty much makes it untestable and puts the configuration logic in the wrong place. You should only accept and validate the parameters passed into the constructor and determine the values and fall backs in either a) factory's create method or b) inside your bootstrapper (if runtime parameters aren't required).

**Don't use View-related type inside your interfaces**

Don't use `ResourceDictionary` in your public interfaces, this will leak View knowledge into your ViewModels and require you to have a reference to the assembly containing View/Application related code (I know I used it above, based on your Locator constructor).

If you need it, pass it as constructor Parameter and implement the class in Application/View assembly, while having your Interface in your ViewModel assembly). Constructors are implementation detail, and can be hidden (by implementing the class in a different assembly which allows reference to the class in question).

**Static classes are evil**

As you already realized, static classes are bad. Inject them is the way to go. Your Application will most likely need a navigation too. So you can put Navigation (Navigate to a certain View), MessageBoxes (display an information) and opening of new Windows (a kind of navigation too) into either one service or a navigation facade (similar to above one) and pass all services related to navigation as a single Dependency into your objects.

**Passing parameters to ViewModel**

Passing parameters can be a bit of a pain in "home-brew" frameworks and you shouldn't pass parameters via ViewModel constructors (prevents DI from resolving it or forcing you to use a factory). Instead consider writing a navigation service (or using exiting framework). Prims has it solved pretty nicely, you got a navigation service (which will do the navigation to a certain View and it's ViewModel and also offers `INavigationAware` interface with `NavigateTo` and `NavigateFrom` methods, which are called when one navigates to a new view (one of this methods parameters can be used to provide parameters to the ViewModel) and when navigating from a ViewModel (i.e. to determine if navigating from a view is viable or to cancel the navigation if necessary, for example: Asking the user to save or discard the data before navigating to the other ViewModel).

But that's bit off-topic.

**Example:**

```
public class ExampleViewModel : ViewModelBase 
{
    public ExampleViewModel(Example2ViewModel example2ViewModel)
    {
    }
}

public class Example2ViewModel : ViewModelBase 
{
    public Example2ViewModel(ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
    {
    }
}

public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase 
{
    public MainWindowViewModel(ExampleViewModel example2ViewModel)
    {
    }
}

// Unity Bootstrapper Configuration 
container.RegisterType<ICustomerRepository, SqlCustomerRepository>();
// You don't need to register Example2ViewModel and ExampleViewModel unless 
// you want change their container lifetime manager or use InjectionFactory
```

To get an resolve instance of your MainWindowViewModel simply do

```
MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel = container.Resolve<MainWindowViewModel>();
```

and Unity will resolve all other dependencies (it will inject `ICustomerRepository` into `Example2ViewModel`, then inject `Example2ViewModel` into `ExampleViewModel` and finally inject `ExampleViewModel` into your `MainWindowViewModel` and return an instance of it.

The catch is: You can't use the `container` inside your ViewModels (though using it in View's code-behind is okay in your use case. However it's better to use navigation Service or a ViewModel Locator within your XAML (see Prism on how they did it)) .

So you need a navigation service of a kind, if you need to do it from ViewModels.

Comment: Does in your examples the service replace the `UnityContainer`? I'd like to add that right now `ExceptionHandler`, `Localizer` and `MyMessageBox` are all part of a class library used in the Example project (if this is of any importance). Secondly, if I understand it right I should move my constructor code into a factory class and only do things like `_appResDic = appResDic;`, assigning default values and exception throwing in the constructors? Finally, please correct me if I'm wrong, but in essence: "DI is extra work in the beginning but will pay off later in the project" ?

Comment: Also, based on your post I guess I do the View and ViewModel binding/initialization, ... correctly? (Previous comment was too long...)

Comment: 1) No, the  `ICoreServiceFacade` wouldn't replace UnityContainer. It just bundles mutiple dependencies that are passed to components, so you just got 1 dependency rather than 3 (Imagine a IComputer facade which contains `ICpuService` and `INetworkService` and `IMemoryService` which. 2) Yes, at least the logic which determines the default parameters (the usage of `Application.Current` inside your Localizer is bad, because this will be a pain in testing if you don't pass anything

Comment: 3) Avoid having `ExampleViewModel = new ExampleViewModel(localizer);` in your code. Instead, consider passing `ExampleViewModel` as a dependency to `MainWindowViewModel` and assign it inside. Don't have scalars in your ViewModel constructors (like strings, integers, floats) or Models as parameter, as this prevents you from resolving the ViewModel via DI container and force you to use `new` keywoard and manually assigning the dependencies, which kind of beats the purpose of it. Use Naigationservice to pass parameters

Comment: On your 3rd point, what if I need a `Example2ViewModel` in `ExampleViewModel` in `MainWindowViewModel`? Would I register all view models in my case in the `App.xaml.cs`? But how would I pass them "correctly" down then? On nr. 2: `Application.Current` is necessary to let the `Localizer` class work because it reads the resource of the application. How can I leave it out then cause I'm still a little puzzled here. Could you update your answer please (even though this isn't the main question).

Comment: You can pass the Application.Current via constructor though or use the `InjecttonFactory` like `container.RegisterType<ILocalizer, Localizer>(new InjectionFactory( (c, t, s) => new Localizer(Application.Current, ...) );` Refer to the Unity documentation on configuration examples (also featuring the `InjectionFactory`, starting at Page 21)